# SA login history in sql

Tags: sql-server, security, powershell

Is there any PowerShell script to get the SA log in history?  I need to do an audit on SA login.

Comment: Can you use logon triggers with help of tsql?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to make sure you are auditing both successful and failed logins

> EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'AuditLevel', REG_DWORD, 1

after a restart you can read the information from the SQL Server errorlog

```
$server = get-item SQLSERVER:\sql\localhost\default
$server.ReadErrorLog() | ? { $_.processInfo -eq 'Logon' -AND $_.Text -match 'sa'}
```

or grab it from the application log